# Crystal Reports Smartsheet not displaying fields

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am using SmartSheet and linking the tables to Crystal Reports in VS2015. When I do this I can see the fields in a Sheet to drag and drop onto the report but they do not show up in the list to link the report together.

How can this be so?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you connecting to Smartsheet data from VS2015? i.e., are you using CDATA's [ODBC driver for Smartsheet](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/smartsheet-odbc-crystalreports.rst), their [ADO.NET provider for Smartsheet](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/smartsheet-ado-crystalreports.rst), or something else?

Comment: ODBC connection.  I would prefer an API but its not supported in VS2015 Crystal add on

Comment: Are you using the [Smartsheet Live Data Connector](https://www.smartsheet.com/apps/smartsheet-odbc) to establish the ODBC connection? I don't see Crystal Reports (VS) in its list of [supported products](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/odbc-docs/#requirements).

Comment: I was using the ODBC connector but after some research i am trailing with some successes this connector.

https://www.cdata.com/drivers/smartsheet/ado/